# Three.js geometry shape stretched?

Tags: three.js

I have a strange problem in Three.js where a geometry is very stretched, vertically.

I'm dynamically loading a picture, and creating a planeGeometry to place it in a scene.

The picture comes in at 196 x 190, and I use a power of 2 function we used before in Away3d to scale the image to the power of 2.  Preiously this was coming out at 512 x 256.

At this size the image doesn't appear at all, so it has to be scaled up to even show. It's possible this is way too big, and part of the image is sticking out the side of the cube that holds the panoramic image.

This picture is stretched out vertically, and not showing the full width or height image - It should be around the same size as the signboard that's partly covering it (that's what it does in Away3d)

[image: stretched]

Here is the code I'm using:

```
 function photo(data){

    console.log(data);

    var texture = new THREE.Texture(texture_placeholder);
    var photoMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: texture,
        overdraw : 0.5
    });

    var image = new Image();
    image.crossOrigin = '';

    image.onload = function() {

        texture.image = this;
        texture.needsUpdate = true;
        texture.repeat.set( 1, 1 );
        texture.mipmaps[ 0 ] = texture.image;
        texture.generateMipmaps = true;

        var w = powerOf2Down(texture.width);
        var scale = w/texture.width;
        var scaledHeight = texture.height * scale;
        var h = powerOf2Up(scaledHeight);

        console.log(w + '/' + h);

        var photoGeom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( w  , h );
        //photoGeom.scale.normalize().multiplyScalar(0.3);
        var photoMesh = new THREE.Mesh( photoGeom, photoMaterial );

        photo.add( photoMesh );
        scene.add( photo );
    };

    image.src = 'http://cdn.beek.co/' + data.file.realName;



    photo = new THREE.Object3D();
    photo.hotspotData = data;


    photo.position.copy( panTiltToVector( data.pan, data.tilt, data.distance ) );
    photo.rotation.x = data.rotationX != null ? -data.rotationX : 0;
    photo.rotation.y = data.rotationY != null ? -data.rotationY : 0;
    photo.rotation.z = data.rotationZ != null ? -data.rotationZ : 0;
    photo.rotation.y += Math.PI;


    //targetList.push( photo );

}

function powerOf2Down(value)
{
    if(value < 80) 
        return 64;
    else if(value < 150) 
        return 128;
    else if(value < 400) 
        return 256;
    else if(value < 800)
        return 512;

    return 1024;
}

 function powerOf2Up(value)
{
    if(value <= 64) 
        return 64;
    else if(value <= 128) 
        return 128;
    else if(value <= 256) 
        return 256;
    else if(value <= 512)
        return 512;

    return 1024;
}
```

Any clues on how to get the full image at a normal size gratefully received!

Answer (score 0):

Was scaling down the wrong thing

```
        photo.scale.normalize().multiplyScalar(0.1);
```